# Error in syncing dependency in android studio like Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

Tags: java, android

Gradle is unable to resolve the `com.android.support:design-v7:27.1.1` dependency, and I get the following error in Android Studio:

**Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design-v7:27.1.1**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm3yG.png)

It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no such artifact as `com.android.support:design-v7:27.1.1`. Gradle couldn't download (resolve) this dependency since it's not valid and not present in the maven repository.

Instead try this `com.android.support:design:27.1.1`, since this is the actual artifact.

Change this in your `build.gradle` and sync again. This should fix the issue.

EDIT:
The `compile` is obsolete and use `implementation` is not the issue here. But please use `implementation` instead of `compile`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**The solution is to upgrade classpath com.google.gms:google-services to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' in file in build.gradle Project:**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

it works